# Factoring out complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm confused on how when we factor out $(a+bi)$, $b-ai)$ becomes $-i$ rather than $i$:

$i * (b-ai) = bi -ai^2 = bi -a*(-1) = bi+a$

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your calculation is right, and so is theirs, because $-i = 1/i$.  You are multiplying $-i$ on the wrong side of the equation: you should show that $(-i)\cdot (a+bi) = b-ai$ to check their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show $(a+bi)(-i) = b-ai$, not $(b-ai)(-i)=a+bi$ (which is false as you pointed out).
$$(a+bi)(-i) = -ai - bi^2 = b-ai$$